# Ajax post returns CSRF error from Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf

I am using python 3.2 and Django 1.6. There seems to be a lot of questions about this but I still don't see what I am doing wrong. Here is the html page:

```
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function() {
    var str = $('#regForm').serialize();
    $('#result').html("Trying to make account...");
    $( '#btn' ).hide();
    $.post( 'ajax/registerSubmit', str, function( data ) {
    if (data.indexOf("you have been logged in.") >= 0) {
        $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location = '';
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        $( "#result" ).append( data );
        $( '#btn' ).show();
    };
    });
});
</script>
<div id="Form" title="Register Form">
<table cellspacing="10" width="100%">
    <form id="regForm" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
           <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="username" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="password1" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Password Confirm:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="password2" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="firstName" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="lastName" size= "30" required /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="tel" name="phone" size= "30" placeholder="##########" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Epa Emts Number:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="epaemtsNumber" size= "30" placeholder="Optional" /></td>
           </tr>
    </form>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="btn">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

This is loaded into a Jquery Dialog box. When I hit submit I get a "POST /trader/ajax/registerSubmit HTTP/1.1" 403 2294 error. Using the dev tools I can see what was actually sent:

In the request header there is this:

```
Cookie: "csrftoken=Xg0AMGcGeMuNhudDnyzZBS7Zc5du10rg;  
         sessionid=7an0o3vq2df6k8qloy1ers37wzt2f2wr"
```

And it says that there were no prams that were sent. I can also add the Django view code it that is needed. I have placed print statements to see how far it gets and it never reaches the 'ajax/registerSubmit.'

Thanks,

Comment: Heres a related post maybe it can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663554/django-csrf-403/24671758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also be sending the CSRF token in your AJAX payload, not just the header.

Given that the token is the same as the one in the session, the common pattern is for the JS to grab it from the session and add it to the payload on every AJAX POST.

See how to do it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I saw that earlier but I could see that it did have a csrf token with it so I assumed that was what that js was doing. For whatever reason it doesn't send the form data with `$('#regForm').serialize()` so I have to do the old `var username = $("input#usernameForm").val();`.