# Django 1.6 HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN header ignored if csrf cookie is missing

Tags: django, django-csrf, django-1.6

I have AJAX code which makes POST requests to a Django 1.6.4 application. The view has CSRF protection enabled via the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`. If I do not pass a cookie but do pass the HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN, it fails.

I am looking at the code of `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and I see that on line  161 it checks to see if `if csrf_token is None:` after getting it from the cookie. If it is None, it returns. Only afterwards does it check the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` param and the `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` request header. This looks incorrect and the check for a missing csrf_token value should only be made after checking all the possible places for where it could be found.

Any one else had similar issues? Am I seeing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 7):

I think the confusion might be that the CSRF cookie and the `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` HTTP header exist on opposite sides of the comparison. In other words, to prevent CSRF attacks, Django compares:

CSRF cookie value vs. POST token value ("csrfmiddlewaretoken")

(or)

CSRF cookie value vs. HTTP header value ("HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN")

That's why the cookie is *always* necessary. Using the `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` header is a substitute for setting the token in POST data, not a substitute for the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can create a beforeSend function that includes the csrf token. [Django CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663554/django-csrf-403/24671758#24671758) for more information.

Please be aware that Django looks for the Header `X-CSRFToken` not `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN`.
At least that was my problem during debugging of the code. (I also checked the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` for this)

---

The `if csrf_token is None` is a extra check done by Django. (Stated from the comment in the  if-statement.

> No CSRF cookie. For POST requests, we insist on a CSRF cookie,
>   and in this way we can avoid all CSRF attacks, including login
>   CSRF.

I think (not sure) there is no single check to only validate the header from a ajax post request,
and Django will do checks to prevent any form of CSRF attacks.

Comment: I am aware of the `beforeSend` and am using it. While the HTTP header is called X-CSRFToken, Django makes it available as HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN, by prepending the HTTP_. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META . This, however, is not my issue. I provide the header value, and Django does not even look at it (please look at the Django source I referenced in the original post)